# Need to return more than 1 value from a recursive fuction in javascript. Needto return the data in the format mentioned

Tags: javascript, object

Code for reference.  There is an issue for the value returned as removeKey, it is always getting a null value.

```
const clearEmpties = (obj: IParms) => {
        var removeKey: string[] = []
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (!obj[key] || typeof obj[key] !== "object") {
                continue
            }
            clearEmpties(obj[key]);
            if (Object.keys(obj[key]).length === 0) {
                removeKey.push(key)
                console.log("k", key, obj[key]);
                delete obj[key];
            }
        }
        return {obj , removeKey};
    }
```

Input for the code snippet is :

```
{"a" :{
"m": {
"m1": "cmp",
"m2": "M2M",
"m3": "2"
}
"p":{}
}
}
```

Output should be : 2 values , return an object by removing all empty objects  & list the removed path.

```
{"a" :{
    "m": {
    "m1": "cmp",
    "m2": "M2M",
    "m3": "2"
    }   
    }
 }
```

&   removeKey = a.p

Comment: Please note: To check if something is a JavaScript object `typeof x === "object"` is not sufficient as `typeof null` and `typeof []` also return `object`. Use `const isObject = (x) => typeof x === "object" && !Array.isArray(x) && x !== null`

Comment: You might get `removeKey` from a recursive call, but as you `clearEmpties(obj[key])` and not assign it to a variable to use it, it might get lost.